# Android ScrollView in fragment too long

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following `Fragment` layout

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_main">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="DEMO TEXT"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_statictext_title"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_statictext_body"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_statictext_title"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The issue I have is that the `ScrollView` is too long. So even though the TextViews do not take up space that is longer than the screen, the ScrollView scrolls twice as much as the screen.

The following Screen is the Preview from Android Studio:

[image: ScrollView Preview]

As you can see it is much much longer than any parent device.

Comment: Have you tried to run it on a device/emulator with the developer settings for "display view borders" enabled?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this before in ADT. It's a super handy preview when you have a ScrollView with so many objects that they just don't fit on one screen.  On the actual device it will scroll or if all the objects fit on the screen you get a scroll hint when you attempt to scroll.

The RelativeLayout is best used to position items relative to each other.  The LinearLayout is best used to position items horizontally or vertically.  The ScollView is best used when you have more than fits on one screen.  Here's an example that doesn't fit on a screen so the tall preview is extremely handy when changes are needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_view_rounded_single"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFollowSpeedDesc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:text="@string/tvFollowSpeedDesc"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbFollowSpeed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cbFollowSpeed" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rgFollowSpeed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdoFollowMPH"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="@string/rdoFollowMPH" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdoFollowKPH"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rdoFollowKPH" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_view_rounded_single"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFollowHeadingup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:text="@string/tvFollowHeadingUp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rgFollowHeading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdoFollowHeadingUp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="@string/rdoFollowHeadingup" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdoFollowNorthUp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rdoFollowNorthUp" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_view_rounded_single"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFollowPreset"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:text="@string/tvFollowPreset"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rgFollowPreset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdoFollowPresetfine"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fine" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdoFollowPresetMedium"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/medium" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rdoFollowPresetCoarse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/coarse" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llGpsReadsPerMinute"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_view_rounded_single"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFollowAdvanced"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="32dp"
                android:text="@string/tvFollowAdvancedHeading"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
            </TextView>

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvFollowAccuracy"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                 android:paddingRight="32dp"
                 android:text="@string/tvFollowAccuracy"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >

            </TextView>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbFollowAccuracy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cbFollowAccuracy" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFollowSecondsHeading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:text="@string/tvFollowSecondsHeading"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
            </TextView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFollowSeekBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                    android:paddingRight="32dp"
                    android:text="@string/tvFollowSeekBar"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvgpsreadsperminute"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/sbFollowMillis"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:max="8000"
                android:progress="4000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/one"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/three"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/five"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/seven"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/nine"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFollowMinDistance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                    android:paddingRight="32dp"
                    android:text="@string/tvFollowMinDistance"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFollowDistance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/sbFollowMinDistance"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:max="20"
                android:progress="10" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="20" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/zero"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/five"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/ten"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/fifteen"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/twenty"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

From:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport

> Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport.

Could this be causing your issue?